# Angular using map but ignoring nulls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dataset that is an array of objects.

It looks something like this:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "john",
  "address": { "number": 42, "street": "High Street"}
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "jane",
  "address": Null
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "hugh",
  "address": { "number": 64, "street": "Long Street"}
 }
]
```

I am trying to get a list of all streets from the dataset by doing something like this:

```
const streets = this.dataset.map((d) => d.address.street).sort();
```

However, due to address sometimes being null, I am getting a `cannot read property street of null` error.

Is there a way I can simply ignore nulls when using the map function?

I tried `.filter(Boolean)` but that doesn't work as the object itself isn't null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by the `address` property:

```js
this.dataset.filter(d => d.address).map(d => d.address.street).sort()
```